# get value from json nonarray fornmat in vue js (backend use laravel)

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js

if i use postman the data to get profile like this

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "status_code": 200,
  "message": "OK",
  "data": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "ahsan",
    "email": "ahsan@gmail.com",
    "email_verified_at": "2019-12-24 08:40:35",
    "password": "$2y$10$cr3bRfqZ3Fp3uxnqgInNCugwAdSNury3Nsn6GMl9T36kxT.36GmzS",
    "remember_token": null,
    "created_at": "2019-12-24 08:40:35",
    "updated_at": "2019-12-24 08:40:35",
    "member_pin": "xxxxxxx",
    "google2fa_secret": null,
    "google_2fa enum \"\"Y\"\",\"\"N\"\",": "N",
    "reff_id": ""
  }
}
```

how to get value? because the data not array format?

i have tried using v-for all data will be showing not rendering like list array format

Comment: This is a JSON data,so you can use JSON.parse() to parse the string.

Comment: It's obvious you're not using Eloquent as you shouldn't be passing around passwords, or their hashes, for security reasons. Plus should you be passing around a Google2fa_secret? You should really take a moment to look at those things.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys` to get all keys as array and use `v-for` to get values

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data:{
    test:{
      "status": "success",
      "status_code": 200,
      "message": "OK",
      "data": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "ahsan",
        "email": "ahsan@gmail.com",
        "email_verified_at": "2019-12-24 08:40:35",
        "password": "$2y$10$cr3bRfqZ3Fp3uxnqgInNCugwAdSNury3Nsn6GMl9T36kxT.36GmzS",
        "remember_token": null,
        "created_at": "2019-12-24 08:40:35",
        "updated_at": "2019-12-24 08:40:35",
        "member_pin": "xxxxxxx",
        "google2fa_secret": null,
        "google_2fa enum \"\"Y\"\",\"\"N\"\",": "N",
        "reff_id": ""
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div v-for="key in Object.keys(test.data)"><strong>{{key}}</strong> : {{test.data[key]}}</div>
</div>
```

Another way to loop in vuejs `v-for="key,index in test.data"`

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data:{
    test:{
      "status": "success",
      "status_code": 200,
      "message": "OK",
      "data": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "ahsan",
        "email": "ahsan@gmail.com",
        "email_verified_at": "2019-12-24 08:40:35",
        "password": "$2y$10$cr3bRfqZ3Fp3uxnqgInNCugwAdSNury3Nsn6GMl9T36kxT.36GmzS",
        "remember_token": null,
        "created_at": "2019-12-24 08:40:35",
        "updated_at": "2019-12-24 08:40:35",
        "member_pin": "xxxxxxx",
        "google2fa_secret": null,
        "google_2fa enum \"\"Y\"\",\"\"N\"\",": "N",
        "reff_id": ""
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div v-for="key,index in test.data"><strong>{{key}}</strong> : {{test.data[index]}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you just need to store the response data in the data property like `user` and then simply write following code in your HTML template:

`{{ user.email }}`

You might not need `v-for` unless you have multiple users.

Consider the following component as an example (for multiple users).

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Users</h1>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Email</th>
                    <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="user in users" :key="user.email">
                    <td> {{ user.email }} </td>
                    <td>{{ user.first_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user.last_name }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            users:null,
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.getUsers(); // Will make Laravel API call
    },
    methods: {
        getUsers(){
            this.axios.get("https://reqres.in/api/users").then((response) => {
                this.users = response.data.data;
            });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```